# Understanding Hadoop snapshots functionality

Tags: hadoop, snapshot, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I try to understand mechanism of Hadoop snapshot (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsSnapshots.html).
Unfortuantly there are very limited amount of information on the official site apache, so post message here.

I tried this functionality on my Hadoop cluster.
Before geting snapshot, I try to use `hdfs dfsadmin -report` utility:

```
[hdfs@bda11node01 ~]$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
...
DFS Used: 15521319604094 (14.12 TB)
```

I make snapshot of durrectory `/tmp` and get subdirrectory:

```
[hdfs@bda11node01 ~]$ hadoop fs -du -s -h  /tmp/.snapshot/snap3
5.1 T  /tmp/.snapshot/snap3
```

Firsh thing that surprised me was size of the snapshot and time to taken this snapshot. Time was immediately, size was the same. 
Second thing that surprised me was report from hdfs utility:

```
[hdfs@bda11node01 ~]$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
    ...
    DFS Used: 15521319604094 (14.12 TB)
```

after this i drop one subdirrectory from /tmp dir and run recovery... This dirrectory was recovered... but i don't understand how. Could anybody describe more details?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HDFS Snapshots are akin to [persistent data structure](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/Persistence.htm) with structural sharing, in that there is no data copying up front for a new snapshot, just a pointer to the source snapshot (more accurately a new record in the inode). Its only on modifications (appends and truncates for HDFS) that record any data. This is similar to Copy on Write (COW) used by many snapshot implementations.

[This work was done in JIRA HDFS-2802](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2802) which has good discussion on the design including HDFS Design document itself. *NB: The discussed RW snapshots are not yet implemented.